# Bubble Sorting an Array of Objects in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, for-loop, oop, bubble-sort

I need to sort an array composed of the `Date` objects by using bubble sort. Objects include private attributes, so I tried to use friend functions. Currently, the program is running but the dates that are printed are unsorted, I guess there are some problems with the use of pointers in the `swap` and `BubbleSortDates` functions. My code is below.

```
#define N 10
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date;
bool compareDates(Date *date1, Date *date2);

class Date
{
    // Data fields
    int Year;
    int Month;
    int Day;

  friend bool compareDates(Date *date1, Date *date2);

public:
    Date(); // Constructor
    Date(int YearIn, int MonthIn, int DayIn);
    bool SetDate(int YearIn, int MonthIn, int DayIn);
    void Print();
};

Date::Date()
{
    Year = 1970;
    Month = 1;
    Day = 1;
}

Date::Date(int YearIn, int MonthIn, int DayIn)
{
    bool IsValid = SetDate(YearIn, MonthIn, DayIn);
    if (!IsValid)
    {
        Year = 1970;
        Month = 1;
        Day = 1;
    }
}


bool Date::SetDate(int YearIn, int MonthIn, int DayIn)
{
    if (YearIn <= 0 || MonthIn <= 0 || DayIn <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    else
    {
        Year = YearIn;
        Month = MonthIn;
        Day = DayIn;
        return true;
    }
}

void Date::Print()
{
    cout << "The day is: " << Day << "/" << Month << "/" << Year << endl;
}

bool compareDates(Date *date1, Date *date2)
{
  if (date1->Year > date2->Year)
    return true;
  else if (date1->Year < date2->Year)
    return false;
  else
  {
    if (date1->Month > date2->Month)
      return true;
    else if (date1->Month < date2->Month)
      return false;
    else
    {
      if (date1->Year > date2->Year)
        return true;
      else if (date1->Year < date2->Year)
        return false;
      else 
        return true;
    }
  }
}

void swap(Date *xp, Date *yp)
{
    Date temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

void BubbleSortDates(Date datesIn[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < N - i - 1; j++)
      {
        Date *date1 = &datesIn[i];
        Date *date2 = &datesIn[j];
        if(compareDates(date1, date2))
        {
          swap(date1, date2);
        }
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      datesIn[i].Print();
    }
}
```

How can I correct those functions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 as it is a good question. Humble suggestion: now that you have a fully-working code (from the nice answers below), share this final version with the Stack Exchange community. You will receive guidelines on how to add lots of important improvements your code currently lacks. Please, don't take me wrong. I sincerely just want to be constructive here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the function `compareDates` in this else statement

```
  else
  {
    if (date1->Month > date2->Month)
      return true;
    else if (date1->Month < date2->Month)
      return false;
    else
    {
      if (date1->Year > date2->Year)
        return true;
      else if (date1->Year < date2->Year)
        return false;
      else 
        return true;
    }
  }
```

It seems you mean

```
  else
  {
    if (date1->Month > date2->Month)
      return true;
    else if (date1->Month < date2->Month)
      return false;
    else
    {
      if (date1->Day > date2->Day)
        return true;
      else if (date1->Day < date2->Day)
        return false;
      else 
        return true;
    }
  }
```

Within the function BubbleSortDates last elements of the array with indices N - i - 1 (in the inner for loop) stay untouched in each iteration of the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < N - i - 1; j++)
  {
  // ...
```

You need to write the loops like

```
for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
{
  for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
  {

  //...
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed is that `compareDates` compares `Year`, `Month` and than `Year` again - instead of `Day`. So that's one thing.